# How to check if output from command contains "error"?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 powershell scripts

`script1.ps1` contains REST calls to Vault, which returns a json response containing some keys/values.

```
Function getValues($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method GET -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response.data| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}

getValues $token
```

As you can see, the method requires a `$token`.

I have that token saved in a system variable.

Now i call `script1` in `script2` to get the keys/values like this:

```
$resp = & ".\script1.ps1" | convertfrom-json
```

that works great and i get values as i need.

however, i am testing when if there is errors in the future, for example by removing the token from the system variable.

This `$resp` returned:

```
errors                
------                
{missing client token}
```

great. now i want to exit the script should that happen.

I tried a check like this:

```
if($resp.tostring().contains("error"))
{
   write-output "error!"
    exit 1
}
```

but it never exited nor did it return the output error!

how am i suppose to look for a match in this case?

Comment: it looks like you need to dig into the _structure_ of the `$resp` variable to find _where_ the value is. i suspect that your `.ToString()` is string-ifying the wrong part of the data structure. try something like `$resp.errors -match 'error'`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey nope didnt work :(

Comment: @Lee_Dailey found another way. all i have to do is just say if($resp.errors) {exit}

Comment: kool! glad to know that you got it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey hey Lee, wanna post an answer so I can accept it? You suggested the solution so you deserve the recognition :) this is what worked :  if($resp.errors) {exit}

Comment: thanks, but i don't think i got it close enuf to qualify as an "answer". your thanks are quite enuf return on my investment ... [*grin*]